# Lambda and VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, lambda, action

I have found this example on StackOverflow:

```
var people = new List<Person> {
    new Person{Name="aaa", Salary=15000, isHip=false}
    ,new Person{Name="aaa", Salary=15000, isHip=false}
    ,new Person{Name="bbb", Salary=20000, isHip=false}
    ,new Person{Name="ccc", Salary=25000, isHip=false}
    ,new Person{Name="ddd", Salary=30000, isHip=false}
    ,new Person{Name="eee", Salary=35000, isHip=false}
};


people.Where(p => p.Salary < 25000).Update(p => p.isHip = true);

foreach (var p in people)
{
Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", p.Name, p.isHip);
}

public static void Update<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action)
{
foreach (var item in source)
    action(item);
}
```

In C# everything works fine.
I tried to convert it in VB.NET.
Here's the code:

```
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
Public Sub Update(Of T)(ByVal source As IEnumerable(Of T), ByVal action As Action(Of T))
    For Each item In source
        action(item)
    Next item
End Sub
```

If I try to update my collection things don't work, though:

```
people.Where(Function(p) p.Salary < 25000).Update(Function(p) p.isHip = true)
```

I am using VS2008 (3.5)
This thing is driving me crazy.

Is there anybody who can help me?

Alberto

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should always post *what exactly is not working*.

---

In your case, you want to `Update` list elements, which works though passing an `Action(Of T)` that should be run for every element.

Such an action, that is just run, performs some side-effects but returns no value is described by exactly one VB construct: A **Sub**.

Thus what you would want to write is

```
.Update(Sub(p) p.isHip = true)
```

which is valid VB2010, but simply does not work in the 2008 version. C# doesn't have a problem there, but in your VB code, you want to pass a `Function` which has to produce a value and not just perform an assignment. `Func(Of ...)` would be the appropriate type of that expression.

**So what to do?**
You can't just express what you want in the syntax of your version. But probably you shouldn't - build a new collection without modifying an old one. Is soon as you're dealing with value types/properties, the above approch won't work at all, since actually a temporary collection returned by `Where` is modified. Linq is no modification language, but a query system.

Anyway: Just use a plain loop.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Dario. I explained what was my problem: "If I try to update my collection things don't work". Anyway, I've found out I can do something like this: .Update(AddressOf UpdateIsHip) where UpdateIsHip is my Function (or Sub) which does exactely what I expected.